# How to deal with error handling in object literals?

Tags: javascript

How can I do some error handling within an object literal?
At least I wanted it to work like this :

```
window.App={
  Variables:{
    "views_data":
      try{
        json_parse(Drupal.settings.royal)
      }
      catch(e){
        JSON.parse(Drupal.settings.royal)
      }        
  }
}
```

Comment: @Lix thanks for editing...so that was not a noob question ;-P ?

Comment: You're welcome @jur! Whether or not your question was a "noob" one depends on who is reading it really. In any case, my edit was mostly to format the code a bit better, and while I was at it, I removed anything that wasn't really related to the actual question at hand. When someone comes across this post in a year or so, the fact that you were a new JS developer will be irrelevant. Take a look [at this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for some more insight into what's considered "noise" in posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an immediately invoked function:

```
window.App = {
    Variables: {
        views_data: (function(){
            var data;
            try{
                data = json_parse(Drupal.settings.royal)
            }
            catch(e){
                data = {}
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `try{...}catch(err){...}` is a control structure, you can not add it to an object literal in javascript. Depending on where you would like to store `Drupal.settings.royal`, you could write your object like this:

```
window.App = {
    Variables: {
        views_data: null    // this is optional
    }
};
```

Now as your object is ready´, you can try adding the parsed json to it:

```
try{
    window.App.Variables.views_data = json_parse(Drupal.settings.royal);
}catch(err){
    window.App.Variables.views_data = JSON.parse(Drupal.settings.royal);
}
```

Nice and clean.

Comment: Well yes. But the question specifically stated **within** object literals.

Answer (score 1):

1) use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression

```
views_data : (function () {
    var result = "",
        json = Drupal.settings.royal;

    try { result = json_parse(json); }
    catch (e) { result = JSON.parse(json); }
    return result;
}())
```

2) Unless there's something special about your `json_parse`, I'd actually recommend doing this the other way around -- using the browser's `JSON.parse`, instead.  The native implementation is going to be faster than pretty much anything that you could write yourself.  Then fall back to handwritten solutions, if `JSON` doesn't exist.  Of course, that's if you aren't doing anything special in your implementation.